# Pyspark, trying to create a column using a variable to fill every single row in the column

Tags: python, database, variables, pyspark

```py
#creating variable based off column value
value = eps.select('value').collect()[0]

#attempting to lit the variable to create an entire column of just this variables output
dfall = dfall.withColumn('test', lit(col(value)))
```

Error message:

> Method col([class java.util.ArrayList]) does not exist

Let me know if you need more code or information, this is my first time posting here

Answer (score 2):

`collect()[0]` returns a row object and not a variable like you want. If you want to get the first element of the 'value' column, you can do `collect()[0][0]`. Also `lit(value)` instead of `lit(col(value))`

```
value = eps.select('value').collect()[0][0]
dfall.withColumn('test', lit(value)).show()
```